# access an activity's standard options menu

Tags: android, unit-testing

I am new to Android SDK, and am working through the [Notepad](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html) tutorial and [testing guides](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/activity_test.html).

I have a simple Notepad app that populates the standard options menu with an "Add Note" option when the device's Menu key is pressed.

I also have a test (an `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` test) for this app. I have a few simple, working test cases:

- test that a "No notes" shows when there are no notes to show
- test that the title of the app is "Notepad"

I want to test that, when the user presses the Menu key:

- the standard options menu is shown
- the standard options menu has one item with text "Add Note"

My difficulty is getting access to this menu in the first place!

I see hooks on the `Activity` class such as `onCreateOptionsMenu`, which are used to close, open, or populate the standard options menu. However, using any of these would change the state of the application, rather than test it.

```
public void testStandardOptionsMenu() {
    this.getInstrumentation().sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU);
    // How to get access to the standard options menu to test:
    // - that it is visible
    // - that it has one option with text "Add note"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out the XML file in the /res/menu folder. That is where you add new menu items

Comment: I am not trying to add new menu items - I am trying to programmatically evaluate the state of the standard options menu during runtime from an automated test. Can you please clarify how `/res/menu/filename.xml` will help me achieve my goal?